# FastCGI SCRIPT_FILENAME causing 500 HTTP error, is this a bug?

Tags: linux, php, nginx, debian, configuration

As I'm struggling for 8 hours to make Nginx works, I (finally) tracked the problem and eventually found it. I was getting  `HTTP 500 ERROR (Internal Server Error)`. I manipulated the configurations for every piece of software I have, but no luck.

Anyway, the problem was  in the `FastCGI SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `FastCGI SCRIPT_NAME` these 2 variables were causing  `500 HTTP ERROR` when including them to the host configuration file. to make it clear, here's some snippets of my configurations.
1. `sites-enabled/default`:

```
   location ~ \.php$
    {
    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/www$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    #including fastcgi_params, is the root of all evil.
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;        
    }
```

2.`fastcgi_params`, the included file(in the previous snippet):

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
#HERE, THE ERROR IS THROWN.
#Commenting the SCRIPT_FILENAME AND SCRIPT_NAME removes the ERROR.
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

as I commented the solution looks simple, but actually, commenting `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` breaks my code since the framework I'm developing on(Codeigniter) is using `SCRIPT_NAME`
to obtain the URL of my website, besides the `SCRIPT_NAME` is assigned to a global variable in PHP(`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`). so I can't comment these 2 lines.

So, what's the solution to this problem, is it a bug? or just misconfiguration?
By the way, the error's log doesn't show anything useful.

Additional information:
1. I'm running Debian 6.
2. using dotdeb build.
3. using PHP5-FPM.
3. I get `403 HTTP` errors when accessing directories.
4. I get Codeigniter's(the framework) custom `404 HTTP` errors when a file was not found.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nginx documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/), you should be using:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

And specifying your `root` directory **outside** of the location blocks:

```
server {
  server_name www.domain.com;
  root /var/www/nginx-default/;
  location / {
    [...]
  }
```